# Save a soft body animation

Tags: animation

i'm pretty new to blender so i'd like to know if it's possible to save an animation of a ball bouncing on a plane made with the soft body modifier. when save the animation in nla editor the ball remain still at the origin. 
And if i press apply modifier it freeze the ball in just one position. thank you for the attention, goodbye

Comment: You mean caching?

Comment: Maybe the OP would like to record the soft body resulting behaviour as animation & deform, in a way similar to what is possible in the game engine, to f-curves so to be able to reuse (as is or after editing) that simulated behaviour?

Answer (score 1):

The "blender game" mode (game engine) can record animations paths for objects, even as soft bodies, but it can be a bit different from the standard "soft bodies" you get in "blender render" mode.

A basic example:

1. open a standard blend file (cube)
2. change to "blender game" mode (pick it form the upper header list)
3. the menu at the left of the engine selection (which you just selected) now has a "game" item: expand it and activate the "record animation" flag
4. now select the cube
5. on the right object panels, go to the physics (bouncing ball icon)
6. choose "soft bodies" as physics type
7. press <kbd>P</kbd>
8. the cube falls
9. when the cube has fallen enough, stop the "game", pressing <kbd>ESC</kbd>
10. the cube is back to start position
11. now switch the viewport to f-curve (graph editor)
12. you see the f-curve recorded for the fallen cube:
13. now change the mode to "blender render" or "cycles render" and use that recorded animation as you wish...

you may have to experiment a bit to get desired behaviour for the soft body and other objects in the scene, but the "blender game" will record everything for you!

manual reference: http://www.blender.org/manual/game_engine/physics/introduction.html#recording-to-keyframes